# How to convert OpenAPI response example content to simple JSON ready for code highlighter?

Tags: swagger, openapi, highlight.js

I want to display example content of a response in `paths.{url}.{method}.responses` section of OpenAPI v3.0.0 specs in `highlight.js`. I am currently getting such object from a remote JSON OpenAPI spec:

```
"responses": {
    "200": {
        "content": {
            "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                    "properties": {
                        "data": {
                            "type": "array",
                            "items": {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/AdminApi-AdminResource"
                            }
                        },
                        "meta": {
                            $ref: "#/components/schemas/PaginationMeta"
                        }
                    },
                    "type": "object"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`#/components/schemas/AdminApi-AdminResource`:

```
{
    "title": "Admin api admin resource",
    "description": "Admin api admin resource",
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "integer",
            "example": 1
        },
        "email": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "admin@test.test"
        },
        "created_at": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "2022-10-17T13:55:59.000000Z"
        },
        "updated_at": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "2022-10-17T13:55:59.000000Z"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

`#/components/schemas/PaginationMeta`:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "current_page": {
            "type": "number",
            "example": 1
        },
        "from": {
            "type": "number",
            "example": 1
        },
        "last_page": {
            "type": "number",
            "example": 1
        },
        "per_page": {
            "type": "number",
            "example": 100
        },
        "to": {
            "type": "number",
            "example": 1
        },
        "total": {
            "type": "number",
            "example": 1
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

What I need is to parse/convert these response objects from OpenAPI to simple JS/JSON objects:

```
{
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "email": "admin@test.test",
                "created_at": "2022-10-17T13:55:59.000000Z",
                "updated_at": "2022-10-17T13:55:59.000000Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    "meta": {
        "current_page": 1,
        "from": 1,
        "last_page": 1,
        "per_page": 100,
        "to": 1,
        "total": 1
    }
}
```

And display these simple objects in code highlighter, for example, `highlight.js`.

I have no idea how to solve this problem or in what direction should I start searching this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of searching, I've found two useful packages that can help to achieve the goals described in the question above.

- `@apidevtools/swagger-parser` - to parse OpenAPI spec and replace `$ref` with the corresponding value from spec components.
- `openapi-sampler` - to generate samples based on OpenAPI payload/response schema to display it in code highlighter.

```js
import SwaggerParser from '@apidevtools/swagger-parser';

// To replace $ref with corresponding value from spec
const dereferencedData = await SwaggerParser.dereference(data);
```

```js
import { sample } from 'openapi-sampler';

/**
 * someEndpointName - is an endpoint name (for example, /test/get/user)
 * httpMethod - get, post, etc.
 * httpStatus - 200, 400, 500, etc.
 * contentType - for example, application/json
 */
const schema = dereferencedData[someEndpointName][httpMethod].responses[httpStatus].content[contentType].schema;

// Simple code in the specified content type
const responseSample = sample(schema);
```